# Using while loop, issue with referencing from static context

Tags: java, while-loop, int, bluej

Currently I am working on an assignment within BlueJ.
The question I have is simple (I hope). The method I wish to use within the while loop is "getRearWheelDrive()" which checks how many Lamborghinis within the **ArrayList< Lamborghini > inventory** have rear wheel drive. rearWheelDrive is a boolean variable.

Also I can not use a for-loop for this question, otherwise I would as it would be much easier. I am limited to the while loop.

The error message I receive is: *"non-static method getIsRearWheelDrive() cannot be referenced from a static context"*  -I tried to create a  static method but it didn't work either.

//

How do I check all the Lamborghini objects within the ArrayList library and then return an int value of how many total have rearWheelDrive? Also with the current code I have, would it cause the loop to finish once it got to the end of the index, or would it infinitely loop?

```
public int howManyAreRearWheelDrive()
{
    int indexPlace = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(indexPlace <= inventory.size()) 
    {
        indexPlace++;
        inventory.get(i);
        i++;

        if(Lamborghini.getIsRearWheelDrive() == true) {
            number++;
        }
    }
    return number;

}
```

Comment: You want the `if` statement to check if *which Lamborghini* has rear-wheel-drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the relevant classes in play here:

```
while(indexPlace < inventory.size()) 
{
    if(inventory.get(indexPlace++).getIsRearWheelDrive() == true) {
        number++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call getIsRearWheelDrive from an instance of the Lambroghini class not from the class itself. Only static variables can be called using the class name which is not the case here.

In this example it would be

```
inventory.get(i).getIsRearWheelDrive();
```